# Style View diffrent for Desktop and Mobile | asp.net core 2 mvc5

Tags: c#, responsive

So I have been doing c# / razor web applications in asp.net core 2 with mvc 5 and got along with it well but now I need to make a new Website which is capable of responsive design.

I baisicly just need to change my view and its css depending on the device the user is on. Im using bootstrap already which does some part of that job already but I just want to style my view diffrently.

Ive gone through loads of turtorials already but all of them arent in asp.net core 2 and use BundleConfigs ect. I havent found a turtorial or template for my framework and version.

This is baisicly just something im looking for and just pseudo code: this is supposed to be a example of the full view. So obviously not an if else for every button.

```
if(device==mobile){
<a class="btn btn-sm">Link</a>
}
else{
<a class="btn btn-lg">Link</a>
}
```

I know that this isnt the perfect question for stackoverflow since im just looking for help and I apologise but im just seraching for either small help or a linked turtorial or something.

Comment: You need to learn about bootstrap... Bootstrap does not require you to write `if-else`.  [read here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/)

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya hahah yeah obviously man i know that. Im completly familiar with bootstrap but I kinda just want my cshtml file to contain something that does something like that if else i showed in my example. The if else is meant as baisicly the full view. So option 1 is mobile view and option 2 desktop view

Comment: The question is well suited for a platform like this I think. No problem. Please check my answer to put you in the right direction.

Comment: @BernoulliIT which one? oh is it hard to do it on that platform?

Comment: Platform = Stack Overflow ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point about Bootstrap is that it is fully focussed on responsive design and uses media queries at certain breakpoints (screen width; xtra large / xl and large / lg display (27" Apple Thunderbolt for example with a browser at full width), medium / md (13" laptop window), small /sm (ipad) and xtra small / xs (iphone).

So there is absolutely no need to use if/else constructs in your cshtml, never. You configure your layout with the use of all these responsive classes wit postfixes like: -xl, -lg, -md, -sm and -xs and Bootstrap (the media queries) do the rest for you according to the window size the page is displayed in.

For your example you could just go this way:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm d-sm-none">Link</a>
<a class="btn btn-lg d-none d-sm-inline-block">Link</a>
```

The first anchor is displayed for a width of the window the page is displayed in smaller than **sm** and from equal to and above **sm** it is hidden (d-sm-none). the second anchor tag is hidden "by default" (d-none) and displayed from the **sm** breakpoint and above (sm, md, lg, xl). For further reference check this [Bootstrap page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/).

So no need for cumbersome if / else constructs in your cshtml.

Comment: Oh yeah that makes sense. One issue though...I want the view to be diffrent. On mobile i want the navbar on bottom like ex. whatsapp has it.

Comment: oh I just realised what you posted there and what it does haha. So could I for example also just add css styling to position one on bottom if its mobile right?

Comment: Of course this is possible with Bootstrap. Just apply the right classes to elements to be shown (or hidden) on mobile devices and elements to be shown on other devices.